# Different results with regular expression literal and regular expression object

Tags: javascript

I have the same regular expression defined in two different ways one with literals and one as an object and surprisingly both produce different results, I can't understand why?

```
let s = "The quick fox";

const r1 = new RegExp('\b\w+\b','g');
const r2 = /\b\w+\b/g;

console.log(s.match(r1));
console.log(s.match(r2));
```

This is ouput for the above code:

```
null
[ 'The', 'quick', 'fox' ]
```

`r1` produces null which is unexpected whereas `r2` produces the expected results. What is the problem with the regular expression object that it is returning null?

Comment: you need to double escape backslash using `new RegExp`

Comment: as for the constructor and passing the regex pattern/code as string argument, one needs to additionally escape any backslash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to escape the backslash in the string.

```js
let s = "The quick fox";

const r1 = new RegExp('\\b\\w+\\b','g');
const r2 = /\b\w+\b/g;

console.log(s.match(r1));
console.log(s.match(r2));
```

Comment: Can you please explain the logic behind it, do I need to escape all the backslashes appearing in the string?

Comment: This at the really basis of JavaScript and many other programming language: "\n" if the newline character while "\\" is the backslash character... if your intention is to make the backslash to be in the string...

Comment: Oh Okay, this is because this is being passed as a String into the constructor, so this follows the basic string behavior. Got it, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In a string backslashes are used to indicate a special character (eg. `\n` is a new line). So if you want to use a string to create a regex you need to escape them.

```js
console.log(`Wrong way to get \w: ${new RegExp('\w')}`);

console.log(`Right way to get \w: ${new RegExp('\\w')}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the constructor which is doing runtime compilation of the regular expression.

You have to use / before and after like this instead of '

const r1 = new RegExp(/\b\w+\b/,'g');

This link will explain everything fast

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: Thanks, I didn't knew we can pass regular expressions in the constructor as well.